# postfix virtual redirect not working properly

Tags: email, redirection, postfix

I setup postfix on one of my server to redirect incoming mails via virtual.db .
I already changed my main.cf and added "virtual_alias_domains" & "virtual_alias_maps"

my "virtual" file looks like this :

```
info@example.org randommail@whatever.com
admin@example.org randommail@whatever.com
contact@example.org randommail@whatever.com
```

when I send emails from myself (in this example from "randommail@whatever.com") - my mails will popup right asap, but if other people try to send emails to "info@example" they won't be delivered - neither they'll come back or send an error report.

I can even see the emails which should be redirect in /var/log/mail.log - but somehow they wont arrive.

*edit*
after I tested a bit more - it seems like I get "some" emails but not all of 'em. For example *@github.com emails won't come through - hotmail on another hand do.
Still the /var/log/mail.log looks fine and the "mailq" command is showing me nothing. I even checked my junkmail folder ... and it's empty.

Does postfix have an own junkmail filter or something like that ?

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n` and the log lines generated by postfix to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a lot of research the problem is not postfix or my server. The problem was and still is the mailserver where the mails get forwarded to.
So funny thing is that the mailserver just blocked the forwarded mails without any real reason without sending any error message back.

So the solution was to forward my mails to somewhere else ...